# Kendo Grid custom editable popup

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I create a custom `popup_editor` [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/IYUYIBaC), and what I want to achieve when `add` new record,

If radio button `Percentage` checked disable amount field, else if radio button `Amount` checked disable percentage field. (refer to image below). And how to do default value in text field? Thank for helping me.

[DOJO DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/IYUYIBaC)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://dojo.telerik.com/IYUYIBaC/3)

> If radio button Percentage checked disable amount field, else if radio
>   button Amount checked disable percentage field. (refer to image below)

```
edit: function(e){
    $('#RadioPercentage').change(
    function(){
               if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
               $("#percentage").removeProp("disabled").removeClass("k-state-disabled");
               $("#amount").prop("disabled", true).addClass("k-state-disabled");
               }
     });
    $('#RadioAmount').change(
    function(){
                $("#amount").removeProp("disabled").removeClass("k-state-disabled");
                $("#percentage").prop("disabled", true).addClass("k-state-disabled");
      });
  },
```

> And how to do default value in text field?

Try this (inside "edit"), every time you open the popup you find that value, if you want to do it once just enter a flag

```
   $("[type='text']").val("default");
```

> Any idea how I can use kendoNumericTextBox for percentage and amount?
>   Appreciate your help

Try [this](https://dojo.telerik.com/IYUYIBaC/15)

Comment: Any idea how I can use `kendoNumericTextBox` for percentage and amount? Appreciate your help.

Comment: If you want to insert kendoNumericTextBox as a mask only to see amounts and percentage with symbols, I advise you not to do it and only change the format of the columns (if you are interested, I edit my answer and I will insert this possibility). If you really want to insert the kendoNumericTextBox type fields, I suggest you ask a separate question.